# Get link at point in UITextView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7, uitextview

iOS 7 supports the new NSLinkAttribute but if you wan't to use it you have to use UITextView. My app uses UITextViews in a tableview to display posts which can contain links.

The catch is that UITextView is first responder so all touches are not send to the tableview or tableviewcell. So what I wanted to see if there is a link under the hit point and if not send the touch to the superview (the cell).

I used the following code in a UITextView subclass but it seems to crash randomly at `[self closestPositionToPoint:point]`.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (self.editable) {
        return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    }
    if (self.attributedText.length > 0 && CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, point)) {
        UITextPosition *position = [self closestPositionToPoint:point];

        UITextPosition *Pos1 = [self positionFromPosition:position offset:-1];
        UITextPosition *Pos2 = [self positionFromPosition:position offset:1];

        UITextRange *range = [self textRangeFromPosition:Pos1 toPosition:Pos2];

        NSInteger startOffset = [self offsetFromPosition:self.beginningOfDocument toPosition:range.start];
        NSInteger endOffset = [self offsetFromPosition:self.beginningOfDocument toPosition:range.end];
        NSRange offsetRange = NSMakeRange(startOffset, endOffset - startOffset);
        NSURL *url = nil;
        if (offsetRange.location == NSNotFound) {
            return self.superview;
        }
        if (offsetRange.location +offsetRange.length > self.attributedText.length) {
            return self.superview;
        }
        @try {
            NSAttributedString *substring = [self.attributedText attributedSubstringFromRange:offsetRange];
            if ([substring length] > 0) {
                url = [substring attribute:NSLinkAttributeName atIndex:0 effectiveRange:Nil];
            }
        }
        @catch (NSException * e) {

        }
        if ([super hitTest:point withEvent:event] == self) {

            if (url) {
                return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
            } else {
                return self.superview;
            }
        } else {
            return[super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
        }
    } else {
        return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    }

}
```

Is there a better way to detect the links in a UITextView? Or what can I do to fix the crash on `[self closestPositionToPoint:point]`?

Comment: That's strange. I use something like your code, and it doesn't crash at `closestPositionToPoint` in iOS7 or iOS6. What's the error?

Comment: Have you tried it on 7.0.3 beta crash logs only show this error for 7.0.3 and haven't had it on 7.0 to 7.0.2. The error is an NSRangeException with a text something like "The index x is invalid" (currently not at a computer).

Comment: Didn't tried on my iPhone in 7.0.3. I'll try it.